# Java reflection - get field value

Tags: java, reflection, field

I try make class which generate new className.java file using reflection. I have problem with Fields value.

Here is my test class.

```
public class ClassTest {
@Deprecated
private int a;


public int[] b;

private final String c = "Hi";
...
}
```

Method in which I try generate fields.

```
private void writeAttributes(Class<?> cls, PrintWriter writer){
    Field[] atr = cls.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : atr) {

        this.writeAnnotations(writer, field.getDeclaredAnnotations());
        writer.write(Modifier.toString(field.getModifiers())+" " + field.getType().getTypeName()+ " " + field.getName());
        try{
            System.out.println(field);
            // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION there
            Object value = field.get(null);
            if(value!= null){
                writer.write(" = " + value.toString());
            }
        }catch(IllegalAccessException ex){

        }
        writer.write(";");
        this.writeNewLine(writer);
    }
}
```

Error is on third field `private final String c = "Hi";`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
```

I have tried add `field.setAccessible(true);` but with there error comes on second field. Any ideas what is bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an instance field, you will need to pass an instance of the class to the `get` method:

```
get(clsInstance);
```

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)) is actually pretty clear about that:

> Throws NullPointerException - if the specified object is null and the field is an instance field.

Comment: And is it possible to get value of `final non-static fields` without instance?

Comment: @dsv_dsv No, this kind of fields could be initialized by `final int i = new Random().nextInt();` which can have different value in each instance.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access private fields by using .getDeclaredFields(). You can only access the public fields.

Comment: This is simply wrong. It is `getFeilds` which can access only public fields (including inherited ones), `getDeclaredFields` returns array with *all fields declared in class* including private ones.